# read patterns from one file and perform string substitution using awk & gsub

Tags: arrays, awk, gsub, gawk

I'm trying to do some massive string substitutions using awk & gsub, reading patterns and their equivalences from a file (dictionary) and substituting them in a second one (input.txt).

`dictionary.txt:`

```
c SUB1
u SUB2
```

I want to store each line in an array, and search the first field (`c` or `u`) in the second file to change it to `SUB1` or `SUB2`. I want to change whole fields, not just string occurrences.

The file I want to modify is `input.txt`:

```
a ca mor
c cq nye
e c ult
d u cult
u as agc
x ul og
```

To make things a little bit more complicated, I only want to apply the substitution in the first and second columns of `file1` (but printing the third nevertheless).

So far I've got this:

```
awk  'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {for (i in a) { gsub(i,a[i],$1)};{ gsub(i,a[i],$2)} }1' dictionary.txt input.txt
```

In the first block I'm storing lines from `dictionary.txt` in the array `a`, using 1 as key and 2 as value (while NR==FNR, while I'm reading the first file).

Then, for each key in the array, I perform 2 substitutions on `input.txt`using gsub (fields $1 and $2).

And this is the current output:

```
a SUB1a mor
SUB1 SUB1q nye
e SUB1 ult
d u cult
SUB2 as agc
x ul og
```

As you can see, I'm currently substitution all instances of `c` for `SUB1`, even if they are part of the field (please note first line, second field. I would like to avoid this.

Also, for some reason, the second substitution (`u` to `SUB2`) is working in the first field (see 5th line, 1st field) but not on the second (see 4th and last lines, 2nd field).

This is the output I need:

```
a ca mor
SUB1 cq nye
e SUB1 ult
d SUB2 cult
SUB2 as agc
x ul og
```

Do you have any ideas on what I'm missing?

Please note that I'm trying to avoid sed-based answers because my real data involves a lot of lines in both files, and it would take too long. Thanks a lot.

Best,

Comment: In `for (i in a) { gsub(i,a[i],$1)};{ gsub(i,a[i],$2)}`, only the first `gsub` is contained in your `for` loop. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Nope, that's an error. When I change it to `{for (i in a) { gsub(i,a[i],$1);gsub(i,a[i],$2)} }` the issue with the second line in the dictionary is solved. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're looking for exact string matches for the whole field, I'd suggest just doing this:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2; next } 
     $1 in a { $1 = a[$1] } $2 in a { $2 = a[$2] } 1' dictionary.txt input.txt
```

Instead of using regular expressions, this simply does a string comparison and makes replacements in the case of an exact match.

Thanks to [dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) for his suggestion.

Comment: You can simplify the syntax some with `$1 in a {$1=a[$1]} $2 in a {$2=a[$2]} 1`

Comment: This one is nice too!

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 you're quite right, that's much better. Edited to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For the whole-word matching problem you can anchor your regexes with `^` and `$`.

And the second issue appears to have been just the extra braces as resolved in the comments, above.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {for (i in a) {re="^"i"$"; sub(re,a[i],$1); sub(re,a[i],$2)}}1' dictionary.txt input.txt
a ca mor
SUB1 cq nye
e SUB1 ult
d SUB2 cult
SUB2 as agc
x ul og
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I didn't know the "^" and "$" syntax could be used to delimit fields, I thought it was only appropriate for lines.